# Google Play Console, question why isn't approved

Tags: flutter, google-play-developer-api

I can't figure out where is the problem I've done everything...missing something?

I have develop app devolped with flutter, I have upload on GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE and for six times always refuse for this reason..

See this screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdR8A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaRdc.png)

Use to choose the PDF, JPG, PNG files and upload the bank transfer receipt to verify that it has been credited or not, also this is also used to download the yoga video

Before I upload on GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE; I have tried with DEBUG, is work perfect

Please help me? I don't know what did I do wrong or what is missing, since you didn't specify exactly what and where to fix

On Android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml there are these code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

O page there are:

```
import 'package:media_store_plus/media_store_plus.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
```

```
final mediaStorePlugin = MediaStore();
```

```
void loadDir() async {

  await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  List<Permission> permissions = [
    Permission.storage,
  ];

  if ((await mediaStorePlugin.getPlatformSDKInt()) >= 33) {
    permissions.add(Permission.photos);
    permissions.add(Permission.videos);
  }

  await permissions.request();
  // we are not checking the status as it is an example app. You should (must) check it in a production app

  // You have set this otherwise it throws AppFolderNotSetException
  MediaStore.appFolder = "MediaStorePlugin";

}
```